# The equation of a curve which is almost similar to Gaussian curve (normal distribution curve) with $2$ asymptotes

Tags: functions, normal-distribution, graphing-functions, curves, gaussian

We know that the equation of the following curve could be of the form $y=A+Be^{ax^2+bx+c}$ where $A,B,a,b,c$ are constants.

[image]

Which has *one* horizontal asymptote.

---

I have (*almost*) same kind of curves (Maybe same as the above one but in more general form). The following has *two* horizontal asymptotes. What could be its equation?

[image]

Please suggest me an explicit (& not piecewise) function.

---

Any help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Answer (score 5):

You can add an s-shaped function.

E.g.

$$5e^{-x^2}+\tanh(2x+x^3).$$

Make sure that it tends to its asymptotes faster than the Gaussian, to avoid a local minimum.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution obtained by adding to a gaussian function a modified $\arctan \ (= \tan^{-1})$ function, namely

$$f(x)=e^{-x^2}+a \arctan(b(x+c))$$

with $a=0.05;b=10;c=0.7.$

I have featured in red the derivative of this function.

[image]